# Асинхронные TcpClient, NetworkStream и SslStream, как задать таймаут соединения?

Tags: c#, .net, асинхронность

В синхронной реализации я использовал простой таймер, который обрубал соединение. В асинхронной я считаю кощунством использовать что-то подобное, не для того я переделывал код под асинхронный, чтобы заводить потоки для таймера.

Как задать таймаут соединения (не `Read\Write` таймаут сокета, а именно соединения) для `TcpClient`, `NetworkStream` и `SslStream`?

Comment: А вы не пробовали `TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout`?

Comment: @VladD, пробовал, не спасает. Соединение затягивается, я подозреваю что из-за reject настроек фаерволла на узлах, или чего то подобного, как и говорил один из пользователей SO. Надо жестко обрубать соединение спустя определенный период времени.

Comment: Мм-да. А если по-простому `Task.WhenAny(ConnectAsync, Task.Delay())`?

Comment: @VladD, не нашел перегрузку `WhenAny`, с возможностью задать таймаут. Попробуй `Wait`, о результатах напишу чуть позже.

Comment: @VladD, `Wait` блокирует метод, скорость теряется. Так что вопрос с таймаутом соединения для сетевых клиентов актуален.

Comment: А зачем таймаут? Если `Task.Delay(timeout)` завершится первым, вы получите управление в этот момент. Никакого `Wait`!

Comment: @VladD, извините, не сразу понял смысл предложенного варианта. Искал перегрузку с таймаутом зачем то)))

Comment: Окей, пробуйте! :)

Comment: @VladD, сработало! =) Добавьте в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout` не работает, в качестве fallback-варианта можно использовать таймер:

```
var connectTask = tcpClient.ConnectAsync(...);
var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout);
var firstFinished = await Task.WhenAny(connectTask, timeoutTask);
if (firstFinished == timeoutTask)
{
    // произошёл таймаут
}
else
{
    await connectTask; // получить исключение, если есть
    ...
}
```

Обратите внимание, что в этом случае, возможно, нужно «убить» `TcpClient` и пересоздать новый (не уверен, обязательно пробуйте!).

Comment: @Alexis: Дополнил ответ.