# TCPclient таймаут соединения

Tags: c#, сетевое-программирование

Как на стороне сервера можно обработать таймаут клиентов, когда тот "тихо" вырубается? На стороне клиента решил эту проблему, если сервер не посылает маленькие пакеты, но для сервера это сложнее, ибо на каждого клиента нужен поток приема пакетов и их обработка, может есть какие-другие способы, менее мои костыльные?

Answer (score 0):

На каждого клиента отдельный поток. Ничего костыльного.

Чтобы не заморачиваться велосипедом, можно включить KeepAlive там и там.

Comment: Если клиентов не десяток, а сотня, то пакетами не зафлудится сервер?

Comment: Интервал можно уменьшить. А ничто не мешает и поднять несколько серверов, "раздавая" их клиентам по очереди...

Comment: Я столкнулся с такой проблемой, клиент ожидает пакет размером в 3 байта, к нему приходит пакет 1 байт (пакет для прослушивания, что сервер жив) и сразу же приходит тот самый пакет в 3 байта, в итоге полученный пакет перезаписывается (в итоге часть пакета просто сместилась) и получается ошибка, какие есть методы исправления? Хотя это уже похоже на отдельный вопрос

Comment: @user292354 Очень странно. `recv()` возвращает фактическое кол-во считанных байт, и этого достаточно. Слова "пакет" в TCP нет, есть буфер, а есть сегмент, в сегментах распределение буферов не должно вас волновать.

Comment: Эээ... Тысяча клиентов = тысяча потоков? Async/await слишком хипстерская технология?

Comment: @SmInc Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Answer (score 0):

В синхронном варианте это решается установкой опций сокета:

```
Socket.SendTimeout
Socket.ReceiveTimeout
```

Далее вам нужно будет обработать исключение сокета, вызванное срабатыванием таймаута соединения в вашем коде.

---

В асинхронном варианте (настоятельно рекомендую переписать синхронный код на асинхронный):

```
// Автор примера VladD, топик: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/505316/292443
var connectTask = socket.ConnectAsync(...);
var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout);
var firstFinished = await Task.WhenAny(connectTask, timeoutTask);
if (firstFinished == timeoutTask)
{
    // произошёл таймаут
}
else
{
    await connectTask; // получить исключение, если есть
    ...
}
```

или

```
internal static async Task<TResult> TimeoutAfter<TResult>(Task<TResult> task, int timeout)
{
    using (var timeoutCTS = new CancellationTokenSource())
    using (var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout, timeoutCTS.Token))
    using (var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, timeoutTask))
    {
        if (completedTask == task)
        {
            timeoutCTS.Cancel();
            return await task;  // Very important in order to propagate exceptions
        }
        else
        {
            throw new TimeoutException("The operation has timed out.");
        }
    }
}

internal static async Task TimeoutAfter(Task task, int timeout)
{
    using (var timeoutCTS = new CancellationTokenSource())
    using (var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout, timeoutCTS.Token))
    using (var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, timeoutTask))
    {
        if (completedTask == task)
        {
            timeoutCTS.Cancel();
            await task;  // Very important in order to propagate exceptions
        }
        else
        {
            throw new TimeoutException("The operation has timed out.");
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно передать задачу каждого действия с сокетом: `ConnectAsync`, `SendAsync`, `ReceiveAsync`, `CloseAsync` - в метод `TimeoutAfter`, пример использования:

```
await TimeoutAfter(socket.ConnectAsync(address, port), timeout);
```